# Sharepoint Provider Hosted App with Angular JS for document retrieval

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, angularjs

I need to create SharePoint Provider Hosted App with Angular JS & MVC for SharePoint Online. That app should perform CRUD Operations on Document Library. When I searched for this, all I got is related to List Items.. But I need it for Documents Library. Is there any working examples for that? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: I would suggest you to do some research on google first and then ask a question here if you don't find any solution or stuck anywhere in code. Some helpful link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/provider-hosted-mvc-app-with-angularjs-part-1/

Comment: @PradipR. I've searched for it, But my bad luck i couldn't find any article related to CRUD operation on documents. Any links to torch how to do would be fine..